# The difference between .bak file and .script file in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

What is the difference between .bak file and .script file in SQL Server? Can you explain it to me?

Comment: Perhaps you mean .sql instead of .script?

Answer (score 0):

One is a backup file, one is a giant SQL query or series of queries in a readable SQL format.